# Using RxJs takeUntil() function with apollo-client

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, redux-observable, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo-Client to make queries and mutations to my GraphQL server. Since Apollo has its own error handling, it's a lot harder to implement the takeUntil function to cancel my query calls and my mutations.

Using Apollo, here is what my mutation looks like:

```
export const languageTimeZoneEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(CHANGE_LANGUAGE)
    .mergeMap(action => client.mutate({
      mutation: languageMutation,
      variables: { id: action.id,  language: action.selected_language }
    }).then(result => changeLanguageFulfilled(result))
      .catch(error => changeLanguageError(error))
  );
};
```

My mutation is made with no problem and if there is an error, it catches it.
The problem here is if I add the `takeUntil()` function like in the example below, my function just doesn't work at all anymore.

```
export const languageTimeZoneEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(CHANGE_LANGUAGE)
    .mergeMap(action => client.mutate({
      mutation: languageMutation,
      variables: { id: action.id,  language: action.selected_language }
    }).then(result => changeLanguageFulfilled(result))
      .catch(error => changeLanguageError(error))
  ).takeUntil("END_LANGUAGE");
};
```

I was wondering if there was a way to be able to use the `takeUntil()` function even if I use a client that has its own error handling.

*The takeUntil() here would be called if I dispatch another action before the mutation is complete.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takeUntil` does not accept a string as its argument. Instead, it expects an Observable which it will subscribe to, using the first next'd value as the signal.

redux-observable is 99.9% just RxJS, so all operators know nothing about redux/actions *except* for `ofType` which is the only operator redux-observable provides--the rest are RxJS built-ins.

There's also a problem of isolation. If you place the `takeUntil` on the outside of your `mergeMap`, you will cancel the entire Epic, not just the particular apollo-client client. Instead, we need to place it *inside* the `mergeMap`, and since we're dealing with a Promise we need to use `Observable.from` to wrap it.

```
export const languageTimeZoneEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(CHANGE_LANGUAGE)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.from(
        client.mutate({
          mutation: languageMutation,
          variables: { id: action.id,  language: action.selected_language }
        })
        .then(result => changeLanguageFulfilled(result))
        .catch(error => changeLanguageError(error))
      )
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('END_LANGUAGE'))
    );
};
```

However, using the Promise `then` and `catch` like this arguably out of place--if you prefer to work with Promises, I might recommend against redux-observable. When using redux-observable, we typically would only work with Promises if we had no other choice (e.g. we don't control the apollo-client API). In these cases, I typically wrap them as quickly as possible as an Observable then the rest is normal RxJS.

```
export const languageTimeZoneEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$.ofType(CHANGE_LANGUAGE)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.from(client.mutate({
        mutation: languageMutation,
        variables: { id: action.id,  language: action.selected_language }
      }))
        .map(result => changeLanguageFulfilled(result))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(
          changeLanguageError(error)
        ))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('END_LANGUAGE'))
    );
};
```

This sometimes means it's more verbose, but mostly it's about not using Promise's `catch` because this can make your code very very hard to follow in redux-observable. "is this Promise catch or Observable catch?". Of course, this is just my opinion :)

---

I assumed that apollo-client has no way of *actually* cancelling a mutation because real Promises are not cancellable. This code will technically just ignore the result of the Promise, rather than truly cancel it (not possible).

Comment: > There's also a problem of isolation. If you place the takeUntil on the outside of your mergeMap, you will cancel the entire Epic, not just the particular apollo-client client.

Yeah part of me knew that but placing the `takeUntil` after `mergeMap` juste gave me an error so I thought I would give it a try.

Comment: Yes Apollo-client has, for now, no way of cancelling the mutation by itself. I like what you did in your second example but like you said it wouldn't **cancel** the mutation but just **ignore** the result. I may try to implement it to at least not show the change to the user and just render the last action he does. Thank you for the answer !

Comment: One last question for you. When I trigger my action that dispatches "END_LANGUAGE", my languageTimeZoneEpic doesn't trigger after that. It works well at start but as soon as I trigger another action to "cancel" it, it doesn't work anymore. Any reason why that is? Thanks @jayphelps

Comment: Hmm that shouldn't be the case with the code I provided--it sounds like the behavior of `takeUntil` being used on the top-level chain, outside the `mergeMap`. If you're not copy-pasting, triple check your takeUntil is in the right place (e.g. you might be off by one in parenthesis). Add a `.do({ error: fn, complete: fn })`  at the end of your epic to see if it's erroring out or completing.

Comment: Great, I changed it from one parenthesis and it works ! The problem is that I can ignore my query results but I can't cancel the mutations I dispatch. It's a start though. Thanks again for the quick answer. Love the library btw. @jayphelps